# Accessing Tables In Lua From C++

Tags: c++, lua, luabridge

I have a global table in Lua I am trying to access from C++.
Here is essentially what I am trying to do:

Lua:

```
myTable = {}
myTable[1] = 1
```

C++:

```
lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
lua_State* L2 = luaL_newstate();
luaL_dofile(L, "luaScript.lua");

LuaRef myTable= getGlobal(L, "myTable");

cout << myTable[0];
```

I get an error on my `cout`, saying:

> Error C2593   'operator <<' is ambiguous  ConsoleApplication2" & "more than one operator "<<" matches these operands:

However I do not think these errors are the issue.

How can I access this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitely convert your `myTable[]` to something << can handle.

And your Lua array starts at 1, but you access [0].

Comment: You are right about that, but that is not the deeper issue I guess. I will update my question to reflect with your change.

Comment: Is `myTable[0]` OK ? Shouldn't it be [1] ?

Comment: You are right, my problem was else where. I will mark this as the answer for future viewers. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. NB for future viewers, you have to restore the original question, otherwise the answer doesn't match.

Comment: Another quick question. If the table were to look like this
test = {}
test[1] = 1
test[2] = 2
globalVolumeContainer[1] = test

How could I access a value?  I thought globalVolumeContainer[1][1]; would work?

Comment: @llya Question needs to be reverted back then.. you can do that yourself via a Suggested Edit.

Comment: I have rejected your edit as it now detracts from the post (I rolled it back before you made the suggestion).